# Is there a way to export a table with large CLOB entries to a flat file?

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to export tables from an Oracle 10g database that contains CLOB data. Some entries consists of large text fields, or specifically in my case, xml files. When trying to export such a table to a flat file, the data in the CLOB gets truncated at ~4000 bytes.

The method I've been trying to use to export the tables are the "Export Database" tool in SQL Developer, exporting to multiple flat file formats (csv, tsv, dsv files..) with different settings. However, it seems as there is some buffer (or similar) that limits the data size and truncates data for all the tested formats.

Does anyone know if this is true? I have not found any such setting (yet, at least). Or if this method is even capable of export such data?

For reference, it successfully exports my largest tables (that do not include CLOB) of about 300 mill rows and a resulting file size of ~12 GB.

The reason for this export is to move the data to an MSSQL database and import it there using BULK INSERT method. The database schema structure is the same (created by the application we use (Teamcenter) that supports both DB systems.) in both Oracle and MSSQL.

Any tips / recommendations is welcome, and if there is another way that should be investigated, suggestions are most welcome.

**EDIT** (17th of March 2020) - For others in the same situation:
Postet my solution as an answer as per good feedback from @MT0 (Better late then never)

Comment: Here is what [google says about it](https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/04/sql-developer-preferences-for-delimited-text-exports/). If DB struncters are same try databse links using minimal code for data pump.

Comment: The issue is probably not the total size of the file but that the `CLOB` is being converted to a `VARCHAR2` during the export and `VARCHAR2` has a limit of 4000 bytes. One method would be to create a database link to the MSSQL database from within Oracle (or vice-versa) and push (or pull) the data over that link bypassing SQL Developer's export.

Comment: @MT0; You are probably right about the VARCHAR2 convertion. I did some more investigations on export formats and exporting data to .xml files seems to work fine for exporting (not that I can explain why), and then converting it to .tsv files for importing to MSSQL. A bit cumbersome, but it is not too many tables that needs this method.

Comment: @eak Glad you solved it but please don't edit answers into your question. Instead you should create a new answer to your own question with a [MCVE] and include your solution there. You can even accept your own answer as your preferred solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by exporting the table(s) as xml format and converting that file to a .tsv file for import to MSSQL using a small script. Had to keep track of field terminators and row terminators in the .tsv file, as the BULK INSERT statement in MSSQL prefers these parameters and they need to be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of SQL Developer should export the data in a way that should be convertible to something for SQL Server. I had a table T with a single row containing a large clob, and when I asked SQL Developer to export it as insert statements, the resultant file looked like

```
Insert into EXPORT_TABLE (X,Y) values (1,
   TO_CLOB('lots of chars...')
|| TO_CLOB('lots of chars...')
|| TO_CLOB('lots of chars...')
|| TO_CLOB('lots of chars...')
|| TO_CLOB('lots of chars...')
|| TO_CLOB('lots of chars...')
|| TO_CLOB('lots of chars...')
|| TO_CLOB('lots of chars...')
|| TO_CLOB('lots of chars...')
|| TO_CLOB('lots of chars...')
|| TO_CLOB('lots of chars...')
...
...
);
```

I don't know SQL Server, but I imagine that could be transposed into something SQL Server could understand ?

Comment: In my tests, the export as insert statements actually dropped the column with the CLOB data. Might have worked with more investigation, but i solved for now using xml export. (Y)